# Is it well-defined to import an identifier starting with `_[a-z0-9]` with `using` into global namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The entire question fits in the title.

C++14 [global.names] says that

> Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

But it's not entirely clear to me if following

```
namespace N
{
    void _foo() {}
}

using N::_foo;
```

breaks the rule or not.

Comment: Or `using std::placeholders::_1;` for a very realistic scenario.

Comment: @hvd That is an implementation feature.

Comment: As N is not the global namespace, you are OK,  and you can use such names as (for example)  class members, but still I cannot see why non-implementors ever use underscore prefixes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The question isn't simply about `N::_foo`, it's specifically about importing `N::_foo` into the global namespace. That's why my example of `using std::placeholders::_1;` is relevant too: importing it into the global namespace is done by user code, that's not an implementation feature.

Comment: @hwd Thanks, missed that.

Comment: @hvd: `_1` doesn't match the "regex" given by OP ;-) That doesn't start with `_[a-z]`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh well. :P Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it obvious? Your code puts a name that begins with an underscore into the global namespace, where such names are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't do that. If the implementation has `_foo` in the global namespace this will produce conflicts.

Comment: If an implementation is written so that such names are never used in headers, there would be no conflicts. But you're probably right.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but you can't guarantee that

Comment: @Sopel It depends on what exactly the above part of the standard means. Implementations may be *required* to work in presence of such `using`s.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- the rule is that the names are reserved. Full stop. Talking about how they might be used helps to understand the reason for the rule, but it doesn't change the rule.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wasn't sure if `using` truly declares affected names in a new namespace, or just alters the lookup. The standard says it's a declaration, thus you seem to be correct.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- the name **is reserved** for use by the implementation. It doesn't have to be a declaration. **You can't use it.** `namespace mine { struct my_struct {}; void _foo(my_struct) { /* whatever */ } } int main() { mine::my_struct m; _foo(m); }` There's no declaration of `_foo` in the global namespace. The name is nevertheless **reserved**, and the call `_foo(m)` is not valid.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair enough.